# Calculating interest on changing principal amount

Tags: finance

I'm writing software and I'm trying to calculate interest on a principal value that changes daily in a predictable way. For example, if you saved $5 each day for five years at a 4% annual interest rate.

I can brute force this calculation, but I imagine there's a better way, which I'm just not aware of. What's the best way to calculate the final principal + interest for the above example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved with a recurrence relation.

Say you deposit $d$ at the beginning of each day.  Overnight, interest is calculated at periodic rate $r$ on the balance in your account, and credited to your account.  Then your balance on day $n$, $B(n)$, satisfies the following:

$$B(1) = d, \\ B(n) = (1+r) \cdot B(n-1) + d, n \geq 2.$$

The solution of this first-order, non-homogeneous difference equation is:

$$B(n) = d\frac{(1+r)^n - 1}{r}.$$

Practically, though, you'll need to carry your values with enough precision so that you don't run into rounding errors too quickly.  If you do, then brute-force calculating each $B(n)$ and rounding as needed each day (as the banks do) will be the most accurate.

Comment: Thanks @John, does this type of equation have a specific name? This answer is perfect for my current implementation, but I'd also like to learn more about this and I don't really know what to search for. :)

Comment: It's a first-order, non-homogeneous difference equation.  First-order because there is only a dependence on the nearest neighbor.  Non-homogeneous because it's not, say, $B(n) = cB(n-1)$, but $B(n) = cB(n-1) + k$.  A broader class of relation applied here is called a recurrence relation.